# JQuery Ajax Call to update a NEW div

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I have a comments system in place which, when submitted, updates a div element with the message submitted.

The HTML

```
<div class="comPostSpan" style="display:none;"></div>
<form method="post" action="javascript:;" class="comStatusForm">                   
    <div class="comStatusForm">
        <input type="text" name="comInput" class="comInput" id="comInput<?php echo $statRow['statID']; ?>" placeholder="Comment...">
        <input type="submit" name="comStat" value="SEND" class="comStat" id="<?php echo $statRow['statID']; ?>">
    </div>
</form>
```

When the first post is submitted div class comPostSpan is updated with the message no problem. BUT, without a page refresh, is a second message is submitted the last meesage is changed to the new message. What I want it to do is add the new message below the last message (I do hope that makes sense).

The JS

```
$(function(){
$('body').on('click', '.comStat', function() {
    var comStatID = $(this).attr("id");
    var comInput = $("#comInput"+comStatID).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"profileAdd.php",
        data: "comInput=" + comInput + "&comStatID=" + comStatID + "&uname=" + "<?php echo $memName; ?>" + "&uID=" + "<?php echo $memID; ?>" + "&statType=" + "statusComment" ,
        dataType : "text",
        success: function(data){
            $('.comPostSpan').fadeIn(3000);
            $('.comPostSpan').html(data);
            $(".comInput").attr("placeholder", "Comment...").val("").focus().blur();
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

I did try wrapping the success function with the following:

```
$('.comPostSpan').each(function(){
    //Success data here...
});
```

But being a JS noob this did not work.

How can I modify this code so that a new .comPostSpan div is created with every post without needing a page refresh?

Help from this community is always appreciated :)

Kindest regards.

Comment: use .append() instead of .html()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.append(data)` instead of `.html(data)`

For Delay:

`.append(data).delay(3000)`

Comment: OMG! I can not believe it was that simple!! Thank you. How do I now fade that second post in as it just appears instantly?

Answer (score 1):

user

```
$('.comPostSpan').append(data)
```

to append messages. When you using

```
$('.comPostSpan').html(data),
```

it overwrites existing text with New text.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like following. First replace the content and then `fadeIn`.

```
 $('.comPostSpan').html(data);
 $('.comPostSpan').fadeIn(3000);
```

Comment: FYI you can't fadeIn the visible element. You need to hide it first. And may be OP is trying to fadeIn the newly appended data.

Comment: It is hidden from first.

Comment: hmm...! correct as per code just seen that. but still _may be OP is trying to fadeIn the newly appended data_ totally my guess as seems to me OP doesn't have any interest in your answer.

Comment: Sorry guys, yes I want to fade in the SECOND post data.

Answer (score 0):

**1st:** As I said in comment

use `.append()` instead of `.html()`

**2nd:** for fadeIn the last message you can use `.promise().done()` to be sure your data already appended then `hide()` and `fadeIn()` the last new message

```
$('.comPostSpan').append(data).promise().done(function(){
    $('.newmessage:last').hide().fadeIn(1000);
});
```

[**Simple Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ye831ffd/1/)

Comment: Just tried implementing that method but no message shows at all when testing.

Comment: @NOJ75 you should check the demo .. the hide() and fadeIn()  will happen for your new message class as you defined it .. In my example I assumed class  .newmessage you should change this with your message outer div class

Comment: Ahh ok, so I have changed the out div class and now it works. However, there is one problem. For example: if 3 posts are submitted without page refresh then all posts fade in and not the latest one. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: <div class="newmessage" style="display:none;"><div class="comPostSpan"></div></div> That is how the DIV's are set up.

Comment: @NOJ75 what is this? is the data returned this code??

Comment: No, these are the HTML div's that I have changed from the code in the OP. Is this wrong?

Comment: @NOJ75 I meant in profileAdd.php .. if new message html something like  <div class="NEW_MESSAGE_CLASS">with new message here</div>  then use  $('.NEW_MESSAGE_CLASS:last').hide().fadeIn(1000);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99198/discussion-between-noj75-and-mohamed-yousef).